# Call to .cmd file causes exit from parent .cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .cmd file which calls another .cmd file, as follows

parent.cmd

```
call "C:\Program Files\Prog1\bin\dostuff.cmd" -abc="def"
```

After def.cmd has run, the dos window skips to the next line, showing the prompt >

The parent.cmd file has therefore completed execution, according to the command prompt. However, after the call to dostuff.cmd, the parent.cmd file is not complete and has a number of other commands to run.

dostuff.cmd sets a number of environment variables and aliases which are required for the remaining commands in parent.cmd. Therefore it is necessary that dostuff.cmd runs in the same command prompt as parent.cmd.

dostuff.cmd is written by someone else and does all sorts of things which I know nothing of. If I call some other .cmd file of my own devising in the way described above, it executes correctly and then the parent.cmd file continues executing afterwards without any problem.

Therefore something in dostuff.cmd is shutting off the processing of parent.cmd. Any ideas what this could be and how I could stop it/get around it?

Here is the parent.cmd program:

```
@echo off
:Begin

echo.hello
call "C:\Program Files\Prog1\bin\dostuff.cmd" -abc="def"
echo.goodbye

:End
```

The output is

```
C:\Users\cowman\desktop>.\parent.cmd

hello
dostuff.cmd text...blah blah

C:\Users\cowman\desktop>
```

As you can see, the echo.goodbye code is not called.

Comment: You will have to show us `parent.cmd` which must be parsing the command line,and to see if it is doing it correctly.

Comment: What does `def.cmd` do? And is it possible that `dostuff.cmd` aborts somehow (e.g. by calling _another_ batch file, but not using `call`

Comment: I don't know what def.cmd does in detail, but I know it sets environment variables and aliases and also creates some files. Yes, it is possible that dostuff.cmd (or indeed def.cmd) aborts somehow. But is it possible for parent.cmd to continue running after dostuff.cmd has aborted for whatever reason?

Comment: Try using `cmd /c` instead of `call`.

Answer (score 2):

Without a listing of `dostuff.cmd`, we're guessing.

My patented guess would be that `dostuff.cmd` itself invokes `cmd`. If you were to respond `exit` to the second prompt, you should then return to the caller (unless `dostuff.cmd` again invokes `cmd`.

if the `exit` response terminates the `cmd` session and closes the window, then that's a real mystery.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "if you were to respond exit to the second prompt". Do you mean that I should put "exit" into the parent.cmd file after the "call" to doStuff.cmd ? I'm guessing you probably don't mean that, in which case where do you mean?

Comment: when you execute `parent.cmd`, you get a response `.../dostuff.cmd text...blah blah

C:\Users\cowman\desktop>` You are now at a prompt. Type `EXIT` and the enter key, and see what happens.

Comment: ok, I've done that. The window does not close, however, when I look at the system variables, I see that those variables which should have been set by dostuff.cmd were not set. (The weird thing is that when I run dostuff.cmd manually from the command prompt and then enter "set", those system variables have been set).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds that `doStuff.cmd` is exited by a syntax error in the batch file while redirecting stream 2 to nul.

A syntax error stops immediatly all batch instances/call stack, but the command window stays open.

I suppose the name of your batch file isn't `doStuff.cmd` and also the parameters are more complex than `-abc="def"`.

As you said in the comments, the command works from the command line, but not from your parent batch, I suppose the parameters contains percent signs or carets.

If they contain percent signs, try to **quadruple** them.
`doStuff.cmd "printf("%d",1)"`
convert it to
`call doStuff.cmd "printf("%%%%d",1)"`

When there are carets involved try something like

```
set "myCaret=^"
call doStuff.cmd "a caret%%myCaret%%"
```

Comment: As you surmised, the batch file isn't doStuff.cmd, however the parameters are not more complicated than -abc="def", they are in fact -cmd="cmd".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like dostuff.cmd is exiting for some reason, which will cause the whole cmd.exe to exit.

Does it have a "exit" command anywhere?, can try changing to "exit /B" to just exit the script not cmd.exe

Comment: When you say "cmd.exe", do you mean the command prompt? Because the command prompt is not actually exited. It is the parent.cmd process which is exited (I presume the dostuff.cmd does something to cause the parent.cmd file to exit).

Comment: yes, command prompt. But if that is not exiting then dostuff.cmd is probably not calling exit which was what I suspected. So must be something else. can you post dostuff.cmd and def.cmd. I'm assuming dostuff.cmd calls def.cmd as you have mentioned it above, that is probably what the -abc="def" parameter is specifiying, is that correct?

Comment: Hi, to my great chagrin, I cannot post either dostuff.cmd (contains very sensitive information about our system - also, dostuff.cmd calls literally dozens of other .cmd files directly or indirectly, and there are exit statements throughout) or def.cmd (as it does not exist, and therefore, to reply to your question, it is not called by dostuff.cmd). Not helpful, I know! P.S. I have tried changing every single exit statement in those files to exit /b but that did not work.

Comment: can your repeat Magoo's suggestin of typing EXIT at the command prompt after running to see if the command window exits or not, but repeat it until it does exit. Just wondering if all the calls to other scripts have left multi layers of nested cmd.exe instances. Would be interesting to see if eventually you get back to parent.cmd and it then runs, before the final window close.

Comment: Also, are any of the further cmd scripts being called using START or without CALL or START i.e. just using the name directly? Those could possible cause effects like you are seeing.

Comment: I typed EXIT once and noticed that the command in parent.cmd after the call to dostuff.cmd was executed. So, as per your theory, EXIT followed by <RETURN> gets me back into parent.cmd and the rest of the parent.cmd file runs. However, adding the command "set" revealed that the variables which dostuff.cmd was supposed to have set were not set. Therefore the rest of parent.cmd, though it runs, produces error messages because it needs some of those variables.

Comment: All the scripts are run with "CALL", or in a couple of cases, "EXEC". No scripts are run using "START" or just using the name directly.